# h:inputText with onchange a4j:jsFunction raises ajax error on form submission when cursor is still in textbox

Tags: jsf-2, input, ajax4jsf

I am trying to use onchange attribute of h:inputText to call ajax function (a4j:jsFunction) which invokes listener attached to inputText. Issue which I am facing is when I update the value of inputText in form and cursor is still in text box, I click on OK to submit the form.

When form submits, ajax error shows up trying to call the ajax function which we have specified. Code looks like this:

```
<form>
    ....
    <h:inputText value="#{somebean}" onchange="changeListener();"/>
    <a4j:jsFunction id="changeListener" name="listener" action="#{action}" limitRender="true" immediate="true" render="#{render}"/>
    ....
 </form>
```

It works absolutely fine, if I move away from text box by clicking tab or clicking mouse elsewhere on the screen.

Please let me know, if there is a way to tackle this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly are you using `a4j:jsFunction` instead of `a4j:ajax`?

Comment: Actually, I am using jquery combo-box and to handle change in value of combo-box, I need to use javascript function because quite a few things depend upon the value specified by user. I simplified the scenario above.

Comment: Code is somewhat like this: `jQuery('.cbClass').combobox({change: function(event,ui) {changeListener();}});`

Comment: Any suggestions for this one? I'm still struggling with this issue.